# How to copy a table structure from one database to another?

Tags: mysql

**How to copy a table structure from one database to another**

Comment: Needs question body, context, ...

Comment: I added the mysql detail, which makes it a little more relevant and focused. This question comes up high on the results for the google search. best not to fight it.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the database in which you want to create the new table, and use `CREATE TABLE... LIKE...`, fully qualifying the source table name.

Comment: More precise reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: Please note that this only works if the user has permission to **both** databases.

Answer (score 8):

Following line of code should do the job:

```
create table new_table_name like existing_table_name;
```

Answer (score 7):

As per comments, it's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Are trying to create a copy of the database (from scratch) or just copy a single table structure across to another database?

In any case, I'd recommend [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

If you want to copy all of the tables, you use:

```
> mysqldump -d $databaseName > $newFile
```

Alternatively, if you only want to copy one table, you can use:

```
> mysqldump -d $databaseName.$tableName > $newFile
```

Then you can you either import this file into the other database...

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple tools that will allow you to view the schema of an existing database and export it as a file that you can then run against the new database. A few that cone to mind:

- [MySQLWorkbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench)
- [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)
- [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

There are many others.

Answer (score 4):

I am looking for the same solution. I tried below example it worked, go to the database where you want to create a table and try like below example.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE database.table_name
```

This example will create a table with AI, Index, Key. its something like duplicate table structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQLyog for this. SQLyog is an all-round Management Tool (/'GUI'/'Frontend') for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple operation, I think is not necessary to dump the database.

My way to solve this:

```
USE TARGET_DB;
CREATE NEW_TABLE LIKE SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE;
```